# Django - how to redirect from a form to a other view of the same app if register not exist, or to other app if exists

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I have a model of clients, and i have a view with a form to check if the client exist using the field dni_cuit

- If the client not exist i need to redirect to a view **addclient**
- If the client exists, I have to take the user to a other view in other app.

Here is the code, I can check if the client exists or not but I can not redirecting properly. Because I always maintain the user in the page **/clients/checkclient**

---

**client/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Client(models.Model):
    dni_cuit = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dni_cuit
```

**client/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

from .forms import NewClientForm, CheckClientForm
from .models import Client


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    title = "Clientes"
    queryset = Client.objects.all()

    context = {
               "title": title,
               "queryset": queryset,
              }
    return render(request, "clients/home.html", context)


def addclient(request):
    title = "Zona Clientes"
    form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
               "title": title,
               "form": form
              }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        # Las 2 lineas anteriores pueden obviarse si solo queremos guardar
        # los datos sin hacer nada con ellos con la siguiente linea
        # form.save()

        context = {
                   "title": "Cliente Añadido - Gracias",
        }

    return render(request, "clients/addclient.html", context)


# Chequeamos si el cliente existe y en caso de existir redireccionamos a
# Nueva orden de trabajo, y si no existe a Nuevo Cliente!
def checkclient(request):
    title = "Comprobar Cliente"

    # Si no hay una variable GET para chequear DNI mostrar formulario para
    # ingresar el DNI del cliente
    if not request.GET:
        form = CheckClientForm(request.GET or None)
        context = {
                   "title": title,
                   "form": form,
                  }
        return render(request, "clients/checkclient.html", context)
    # Si hay una variable GET procedemos a hacer el chequeo del cliente
    else:
        dni_cuit = request.GET['dni_cuit']
        # Revisamos si el cliente existe y direccionamos a crear orden
        try:
            client = Client.objects.get(dni_cuit=dni_cuit)
            context = {
                       "client": client
                      }

            return render_to_response("workorder/home.html", context)
        # Si el cliente NO existe enviamos a agregar nuevo cliente
        except:
            context = {
                       "dni_cuit": dni_cuit
                      }
            print("El CLIENTE NO EXISTE EN LA BD!!!")
            return render_to_response("clients/addclient.html", context)
```

and the other app is work_order, this has other view to add orders there is where I have to take the user if the client exists!

**work_order/views.py**

```
def addorder(request):
    title = "Nueva Orden de trabajo"
    form = NewOrderForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
               "title": title,
               "form": form
              }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        # Las 2 lineas anteriores pueden obviarse si solo queremos guardar
        # los datos sin hacer nada con ellos con la siguiente linea
        # form.save()

        context = {
                   "title": "Orden Creada",
        }

    return render(request, "workorders/addorder.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you add more info like what happens, does it redirect to clients/checkclient.html instead of clients/addclient.html, or does it give error?

Comment: you are not doing any redirects in the code above... you are just rendering different templates. Are you confused about the difference between template paths (locations of html files in your project) and url paths (defined in `urls.py`) ?

Comment: Exactly! that's what happens to me. I'm redirecting to a template but i want to redirecto other view!!!

Can you tell me how to redirect to other view?

I don't get any error in the code, but when i clic the button i'm rendering the same url clients/checkclient but with other template!

the template addclient.html when the client exist or the addorder.html when the client not exists!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "Anentropic".

The solution is

```
return redirect('my_view_url_name')
```

I have one more problem now but is for other question. I need to pass the GET Variable from one view to other using redirect.

Thanks for your help!!!